# Mixed Anova in R

Tags: r, statistics, anova

I am trying to do an anova anaysis in R on a data set with one within factor and one between factor. The data is from an experiment to test the similarity of two testing methods. Each subject was tested in Method 1 and Method 2 (the within factor) as well as being in one of 4 different groups (the between factor). I have tried using the aov, the Anova(in car package), and the ezAnova functions. I am getting wrong values for every method I try. I am not sure where my mistake is, if its a lack of understanding of R or the Anova itself. I included the code I used that I feel should be working. I have tried a ton of variations of this hoping to stumble on the answer. This set of data is balanced but I have a lot of similar data sets and many are unblanced. Thanks for any help you can provide.

```
library(car)
library(ez)

#set up data
sample_data <- data.frame(Subject=rep(1:20,2),Method=rep(c('Method1','Method2'),each=20),Level=rep(rep(c('Level1','Level2','Level3','Level4'),each=5),2))
sample_data$Result <- c(4.76,5.03,4.97,4.70,5.03,6.43,6.44,6.43,6.39,6.40,5.31,4.54,5.07,4.99,4.79,4.93,5.36,4.81,4.71,5.06,4.72,5.10,4.99,4.61,5.10,6.45,6.62,6.37,6.42,6.43,5.22,4.72,5.03,4.98,4.59,5.06,5.29,4.87,4.81,5.07)
sample_data[, 'Subject'] <- as.factor(sample_data[, 'Subject'])
#Set the contrats if needed to run type 3 sums of square for unblanaced data
#options(contrats=c("contr.sum","contr.poly"))

#With aov method as I understand it 'should' work
anova_aov <- aov(Result ~ Method*Level + Error(Subject/Method),data=test_data)
print(summary(anova_aov))

#ezAnova method,
anova_ez = ezANOVA(data=sample_data, wid=Subject, dv = Result, within = Method, between=Level, detailed = TRUE, type=3)
print(anova_ez)
```

Also, the values I should be getting as output by SAS

[SAS Anova](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtX1H.png)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your R code is correct in both cases. Running these data through SPSS yielded the same result. SAS, like SPSS, seems to require that the levels of the within factor appear in separate columns. You will end up with 20 rows instead of 40. An arrangmement like the one below might give you the desired result in SAS:

Subject Level Method1 Method2

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The SAS results are actually the correct results. The p values dont make sense from my R code. The degrees of freedom are odd to me in the when looking at the SAS code, as is the error term that was used to calculate the F value. In the SAS results Level(Method) was used as the error to calc the F value. I think I am misunderstanding the statistics involved here.

Comment: Playing around with the aov function I found that using                       aov(Result ~ Method/Level + Error(Method:Level),data=sample_data) gives me results similar to the SAS output. I dont know what this implies about the set up of the experiment and the Anova though. I would not of thought to model it in this way.